# Encrypt config file for HttpHandler

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, iis-7

I have "Class library projet" which works as HttpHandler later at a webserver. So I have locally 2 files app.config (for local dev, because it is a dll) and web.config (for remote web server).

So now I wanted to encrypt config file. Everything was encrypted and imported at remote web server. But the handler doesn't work. I receive an error: `"Failed to decrypt using provider 'My_Provider'. Error message from the provider: The RSA key container could not be opened."`

At my dev PC everything works fine. What is wrong?

So this my export steps

> cd %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
>
> aspnet_regiis -pc "My_Keys" -exp
>
> aspnet_regiis -pa "My_Keys" "IIS APPPOOL\CustomAppPool"
>
> aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" "HandlerProjectPath"  -prov
>   "My_Provider"
>
> aspnet_regiis -px "MyKeys" "HandlerProjectPath\MyKeys.xml" -pri
>
> pause

these are import step

> %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -pi
>   "My_Keys" "MyKeys.xml"
>
> pause

p.s. My handler works at IIS 7 inside my custom AppPool with name "CustomAppPool". I specially created an app pool name at my PC.

this is my configData

> Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a,
>
>   
>               processorArchitecture=MSIL"
>
> ```
>        keyContainerName="My_Keys"
>        useMachineContainer="true" />
> </providers>   </configProtectedData>
> ```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to grant access to the container to the IIS Identity assigned to your AppPool, after you import the key pair.